Degree of irreducible factor of an irreducible polynomial after field extension
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$ (or a perfect field, whatever), $P$ be an irreducible polynomial in $k[x]$ of degree $d$. Let $L/k$ be a finite field extension of $k$. Then $P$ can decompose to $\prod P_i$ such that $P_i$ is irreducible in $L[x]$ for any $i$.
Can we prove that there exists $i$ such that $\mathrm{deg}(P_i)\mid \mathrm{deg}(P)$ for some $i$? Or can we find a counterexample that $\mathrm{deg}(P_i)\nmid \mathrm{deg}(P)$ for any $i$?

When $L/k$ is a Galois extension, it is easy to prove because all the $P_i$ have same degree, so I want to know what it would be like when $L/k$ is a general extension.

Good question. Have you checked some examples of non-normal extensions?

Denote by $a_i$ a root of $P_i$ in an algebraic closure of $k$. We have $$[L(a_i):k]=[L(a_i):L][L:k]=[L(a_i):k(a_i)][k(a_i):k]$$ which gives $[k(a_i):k]=([L(a_i):L][L:k])/[L(a_i):k(a_i)]$. Note that $\deg(P)=[k(a_i):k]$ and $\deg(P_i)=[L(a_i):L]$. If $\deg(P_i)\nmid \deg(P)$ then $[L:k]/[L(a_i):k(a_i)]$ cannot be an integer. This is where I got stuck tho.

@MartinBrandenburg I have calculated some simple examples. For example, let $k=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$, $P=x^3-2$. Then $P$ decomposes into $P_1P_2=(x-\sqrt[3]{2})(x^2+\sqrt[3]{2}x+\sqrt[3]{4})$. In this case $\mathrm{deg}(P_1)|\mathrm{deg}(P)$ but $\mathrm{deg}(P_2)\nmid\mathrm{deg}(P)$. I have not find a counterexampel yet.

@schiepy In the upon example, if $a$ is a root of $P_2$, then $[L:k]/[L(a):k(a)]$ is not an integer.

@dhan I actually had the same example, but didn't realize that $2\nmid 3$. Haha, I'm dumb sometimes.

Let $f$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n$ with Galois group $S_n$. Then for any partition of $n$ there is an extension of $k$ in which $f$ factors into a product of irreducibles where the factors have degrees given by the partition. Indeed, let $n=n_1+\dots+n_m$ be a partition of $n$ and let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$. Then consider the subgroup $H=S_{n_1}\times\dots\times S_{n_m}\subseteq S_n$ in $\operatorname{Gal}(L/k)\cong S_n$. Let $K\subseteq L$ be the fixed field under this subgroup. Then $f$ factors in $K$ as $\prod_{i=1}^mf_i$ where $f_i$ has degree $n_i$.
So in particular there are examples for every $n=\deg f\geq5$.
To see that $f$ factors like that in $K$, let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ be a fixed ordering of the roots (corresponding to the isomorphism $S_n\cong \operatorname{Gal}(L/k)$), and let $f_i=\prod_{j=n_1+\dots+n_{i-1}+1}^{n_1+\dots+n_i}(t-\alpha_j)$. Then $f_i$ is invariant under $H$, so $f_i$ has coefficients in $K$, and $H$ permutes the roots of $f_i$ transitively, so it is irreducible over $K$, and clearly $\prod_{i=1}^mf_i=f$.

The question is that if we can find such $f$ of degree $n$ s.t. the Galois group of its splitting field is $S_n$. Do you know any methods to confirm the existence of such $f$?

For example the `generic' polynomial of degree $n$: $T^n+X_1T^{n-1}+\dots+X_n\in k(X_1,\dots,X_n)[T]$ has Galois group $S_n$. An example over $\Bbb Q$ is given by $x^n-x-1$

Also the assumption that the Galois group is $S_n$ could be relaxed: All we need is that given our partition, the Galois group (identified with a subgroup of $S_n$) contains a subgroup of the form $H_1\times\dots\times H_m$ where each $H_i$ acts transitively on ${n_1+\dots+n_{i-1}+1,\dots,n_1+\dots+n_i}$ and fixes the remaining elements. Though I am not sure how much this helps

At least for $n=5$ and the partition $5=2+3$ (which would be the smallest possible counterexample) it cannot be done simpler (with a smaller group than $S_5$) because any transitive subgroup containing a transposition would be all of $S_5$

Wait, isn't the example given by dhan in the comments a counterexample of smaller degree? Or do you mean a counterexample where $\deg(P_i)\nmid \deg(P)$ for all $i$?

I mean an example where $\deg(P_i)\nmid \deg (P)$ for all $i$. Because if the degree is at most $4$, then there is always a factor with degree dividing $n$ (what are the possible degrees in a factorization of a polynomial of degree $\leq4$?)

Alright, gotcha.
